# Specify StructureMap lifespan explicitly

Tags: c#, structuremap

In my web application, I've configured StructureMap to scope a single database session per HTTP request.

```
For<ISession>()
    .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
    .Use(context => /* construct the session here */);
```

I now have another class which requires a *brand new* session every time I construct it.

```
public class NewClass 
{
    public NewClass(ISession session)
    {
        /* do some stuff with the session */
    }
}
```

How do I configure StructureMap so that when I call `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<NewClass>()`, it will get a new session each time? I want to leave the default behaviour untouched, so that all my other classes are left with a session per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StructureMap has a [built in limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11120111/66849) in that a registered interface can only have one lifetime. You need to work around this by having two different interfaces for `ISession`:

```
conf.For<INewSession>().Use(context => ...);
conf.For<ISession>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(context => ...);
```

where `NewClass` takes a `INewSession` as a dependency and

```
interface INewSession : ISession
```